# State List Drawable: Overrite default colors in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a state list selector to give my ImageView a different background color when they are pressed/focused:

```
<!--lightbutton_selector.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightbutton_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/lightbutton_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lightbutton_default"/>
</selector>
```

with the inidividual states looking like this:

```
<!--lightbutton_pressed.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/yellow" />
</shape>
```

It works if I set it like this in XML

```
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
    ...
```

But now I have several buttons in a row with different colors:

[image: colored buttons]

whose background should change according to the selector, i.e. if I keep the right-most one pressed:

[image]

My goal is to specify the button's different colors together with the state selector in XML. **Is this possible without creating a new selector drawable for every color red,green,grey?**

I would usually set the color like this, which obviously overwrites the background selector:

```
<ImageView
    android:background="@color/negative"
    ...
```

**What I have tried (unsuccessfully):**

1.The color changes to yellow upon selection but the default color is not set

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:drawable="@color/grey"
    android:background="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
    ...
```

2.Vice-Versa: The default color is set, but the selector does not change

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
    ...
```

3.The tint applies to all colors so the selection color is grey, not yellow

```
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:background="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
    ...
```

Comment: see `StateListDrawable` documentation

Comment: Did so, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) looks nice .... ;-) Do you have a specific part in mind?

Comment: yes: `addState`

Comment: thanks. does not look like this is usable to set the button-specific color from XML, though, does it?

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: Since I want a specific color for each button ``without creating a new selector drawable for every color red,green,grey`` I would have to add an XML attribute to the <ImageView> tag to accomplish this. But it is not clear to me, which one (cf. the unsuccessful tries list). One of the reasons why I would want this to happen in XML only is so that I can add buttons in the future just by copy-pasting them (and not forgetting some layout code in my ViewHolder class). The other reason is curiosity

Comment: use `View#setBackground`, if you want to do all of it in xml the only way for a dynamic colors is [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: I did not know of DataBinding. A whole new world... :-) thanks, will take a look into it

Comment: but why dont you want to call `View#setBackground` with your `SLD` directly from java code?